# Python Multiplication ,sum arrays with different length: Optimise code

Tags: python, numpy, sum, shapes

I try to Manipulate arrays of different shapes.
When I try np.sum or np.multiply
i get ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (60,) (37,)

How can I resolve shapes error?
if i add "0/1" when i calculate "SUM/multiply"  wwill be a good idea?

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: **We don't have the full error message, or a [mcve].**

Comment: Can't you simplify the example to something using just 2 arrays?  And then show exactly what behavior you expect.  Obviously an array of shape (60,) cannot added or multiplied with one that is (37,).   But the fix depends on what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
import numpy as np

def zero_pad(a, newlen):
    result = np.zeros(newlen, dtype=a.dtype)
    result[:len(a)] = a
    return result
    # alternatively: return np.pad(a, (0, newlen - len(a)), 'constant')


def get_value(a, b, c, d, e):
    maxlen = max([len(ar) for ar in [a, b, c, d, e]])
    a = zero_pad(a, maxlen)
    b = zero_pad(b, maxlen)
    c = zero_pad(c, maxlen)
    d = zero_pad(d, maxlen)
    e = zero_pad(e, maxlen)
    return a + (b * d) + (c * e)

print(get_value(np.arange(4), np.arange(8), np.arange(3), np.arange(2), np.arange(5)))
```